# Como resgatar um item de um relacionamento com swift?

Tags: ios, swift-3, core-data

Olá estou tentando armazenar em uma variável o valor de um item de um relacionamento.O relacionamento é "amigos" e nele existem alguns atributos como "amizade".Eu gostaria de armazenar o valor de "amizade" nesta variável mas não estou conseguindo.Como exemplo em Nspredicate eu uso "amigos.amizade" para acessar o item de um relacionamento , mas fora do nspredicate não consigo obter esse valor , alguém ai pode ajudar?Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Consegui acessar o atributo do relacionamento utilizando em vez de vafalue for key usei value for key path e passando como parâmetro ("relacionamento.atributo")